# Observable for mutiple responses in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs

So, I have this service which first calls a function from another module which basically returns an list of urls from an external api. This service then must `http.get` from all the urls in that list (every url returns a json object of same format) then return a single observable which I can then use in an angular `component`. Here's what my service code looks like:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { Client } from 'external-api';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    let client = new Client();

    @Injectable()
    export class GbDataService {
      constructor(private _http: Http) {

      }

        getGBData(): Observable<any> {
        client.fetchUrls("").then(resp=> {
        resp.forEach(url => {
          //this._http.get(url).map(res => res.json);
          // Create a single observable for every http response

        });
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        });
        //return observable
      };
   }
```

`http.get` returns and `Observable<Response>` type but I couldn't find a way to create and return one Observable for all http.get responses. How can this be done ? Should I create an observable array then `push()` all the `get` response I get to the array?

**EDIT**: It doesn't really matters to me if responses are emitted one by one or all at once BUT there must be only a single Obeservable which emits the responses of all the `http.get` requests.

**Further Edit**: This is my fetchURLs method:

```
  fetchURLs(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let _repos: Array<any>;
      //scrapeTrendingRepos() is from https://github.com/rhysd/node-github-trend
      scraper.scrapeTrendingRepos("").then(repos => {
        repos.forEach(repo => {
          let url = `https:api.github.com/repos/${repo.owner}/${repo.name}`;
          _repos.push(url);
        });
        resolve(_repos);
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
  };
```

Have I implemented Promises in `fetchURLs()` right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you make a request and get back an array of URLs that you then want to fetch all and get one response from?

Those are the types of things that RxJS excels at.

```
@Injectable()
    export class GbDataService {
      constructor(private _http: Http) {

      }

      getGBData(): Observable<any> {

        return Observable
          .fromPromise(client.fetchUrls())   // returns Observable<array>
          .switchMap( urls => {  
            // convert your list of urls to a list of http requests
            let urlRequests = urls.map( url => http.get(url) );

            // combineLatest accepts an array of observables,
            // and emits an array of the last results of each of the observables
            // but the first emit only happens after every single observable
            // has emitted its first result

            // TLDR: combineLatest takes an array of Observables
            //       and will emit an array of those observable emissions       //       after all have emitted at least once
            return Observable.combineLatest(urlRequests);

          })
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        });
        //return observable
      };
   }
```

**Further info:**

Read up on the combineLatest observable. In this scenario, it accomplishes what you want of waiting for all its observable arguments to emit before emitting a single array. But if your observable arguments also emit multiple times, it may not do what you expect and you might want to try a different operator like forkJoin or zip.

**Additionally**

You might want to use switchMap rather than flatMap - if a new request for urls to fetch comes through, switchMap will cancel any requests currently in flight before sending the new list of requests.

**Further Edit**

Although your fetchURLs implementation can work in its current incarnation, you can simplify your method a bit if you wish by taking advantage of how promises work. In 'Promise-land', the `then` handler also returns a `Promise`, and that second `Promise` will resolve with whatever value you return from your `then` handler *(this is the basic promise chaining concept)*. Using that knowledge, you can simplify your method to:

```
fetchURLs(): Promise<any> {
  //scrapeTrendingRepos() is from https://github.com/rhysd/node-github-trend
  return scraper.scrapeTrendingRepos("").then(repos => {
     // since repos is an array, and you wish to transform each value
     // in that array to a new value, you can use Array.map
     return repos.map( repo => `https:api.github.com/repos/${repo.owner}/${repo.name}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: you assme that `client.fetchUrls` return a native `Promise`, because it may return a promise implemented by other library

Comment: well, once the promise returned is thenable (i.e. you call` .then` to get your resolved value), `fromPromise` would work.  You can check the source if you wish  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/PromiseObservable.ts

Comment: @snorkpete @BougarfaouiElhoucine `client.fetchUrls` returns an array of strings like `['http url #1', 'url #2'...]` so I'm passing `Promise.resolve(client.fetchUrls())` into the `fromPromise()`, is this the correct way ? Also. When I do `let urlRequests = urls.map()` it gives an error `[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type '() => any[]'.` although i've imported the rxjs map function in to my service.ts.

Comment: can you show the code of `client.fetchUrls` method please

Comment: @EdwardMcKinzie, as  Bougarfaoui El houcine mentioned, could you include the code for fetchUrls?  i also have a typo in my code..  fromPromise expects its parameter to be a promise, and i was passing it a function... updated the code to pass the result of calling client.fetchUrls, rather than the function itself. my apologies

Comment: what you pass to Observable.fromPromise() should be a promise. If client.fetchUrls returns a promise, then there's no need for extra wrapping

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine @snorkpete I've modified `fetchURLs()` to return a promise, my main problem now is I get a couple of errors on `let urlRequests = urls.map( url => http.get(url) );`, it says `Argument of type '(urls: () => any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: () => any[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'`, i'm also having problems in `urls.map()` which I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: the error you're seeing has to do with the return value of your fetchUrls() method - can you post that fetchUrls code so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I've added my fetchURLs function, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

if `client.fetchUrls("")` return a **native** `Promise` you may want to use  [snorkpete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11742/snorkpete) solution.

if not try to create an observable:

```
getGBData(): Observable<any> {

   return Observable.create(observer => {
        client.fetchUrls("").then(resp=> {
        resp.forEach(url => {
          this._http.get(url).map(res => res.json).subscribe(data=>{
            observer.next(data);
          });


        });
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            observer.error(err);
        });
  });
}
```

Comment: In your case, you will end up emitting each http result separately. I believe he wanted the observable to only emit once with all the results - although i may be wrong about that.